# Application.Exit() not exiting the Application or Process

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, process, ipc

I have windows application as a process that will launch UI application as well as other processes for Inter Process Communication.

For System End Functionality, in UI when END button is clicked it is has to exit all the processes that are running as part of application.

All other processes are subscribed to ProcessEnd delegate event which is published from UI Process.

The other processes are run as hidden windows form application and only main UI Process is shown to user.

*But the problem is when Application.Exit() is called on ProcessEnd Method in the respective process, Process is gracefully exited in Windows XP through Application.Exit(). But in Windows 10 OS, the process is not getting exited.*

when i analyzed further through threads debugger, here is what i could see as below[image]

I could see there are 6 threads running before this.Close() called on ProcessEnd. After this.Close() method called, then 2 threads are running as shown below - OnClosing i am terminating all the worker threads:

[image]

Can i assume that because of 9744 ThreadID as shown above, is this process not exited or how can i know what i causing this Process not to exit ?

Comment: Does it eventually close?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen : Yes it causing the windows to close after this.Close() is called

Comment: If something is blocking like a thread or a form, you can try Application.Exit and as a last resort Environment.Exit, but check that nothing disallow close or block before using that. Also try to click on the pause button of Visual Studio to go to the blocking code and unless it is in the core of .NET you will have your villain line on the screen... If IPC blocks and can't fix it properly, review your design or take a look at [that](https://github.com/Ordisoftware/Hebrew-Calendar/blob/dedea9284a6385822af78b718e6c9337d47675b9/Project/Source/Forms/MainForm/Reminder/MainForm.Reminder.cs#L167).

Comment: @OlivierRogier : Yes i tried Application.Exit() but the behaviour is still the same. Environment.Exit(0) works but i don't think it is a good idea to forcefully exit the process.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was being unclear. When you call `this.Close()`, expecting the process to terminate, does it eventually terminate? Or does it stay running "forever"?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen : Yes i am expecting the process to exit/terminate whenever this.Close() or Application.Exit() is called. However this does not happen and runs for ever. Yes i have a timer to kill forcefully after certain time. But this same piece of code works in Windows XP operating system i.e. it terminates process on call of this.Close() or Application.Exit()

Comment: Please be more specific, what do you mean by 'this.Close()'. And how do you start your worker threads? Are they [background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isbackground?view=net-5.0) threads?

Comment: @Steeve : I edited my question. It is Application.Exit not this.Close. Threads are started once the application starts and by default they are foreground threads.

Comment: @Amarnath, than you already know why Application.Exit won't exit. So the simplest solution is to set IsBackground of your threads to true before starting them, if you don't care how they get terminated.